# Days remaining in specific date for every month

Tags: javascript, momentjs

At the moment I don't have any code, because I don't know where to start.

I have to manage subscription on my app. So, if user installed the app on 8th Sep then it will get renewed automatically on 8th October similar for every month. But I would like to show days remaining.

I have stored the date of installation in database. For one month I can do that easily using moment.js or angular way. Like below.

```
var a = moment([2017, 09, 29]);
var b = moment([2017, 10, 28]);
 Math.abs(a.diff(b, 'days'))+1
```

How can I achieve this?

### More explanation

I don't need to get the current date. I want to show renew days for subscription. If someone installed on 4th Aug then it get renewed automatically on 4th Sep and next renew date will be 4th Oct. So, I want to show days remaining till 4th Oct.

Comment: Just check how far they are away from the 8th on the next month??? If you can't figure it out, write it on a piece of paper, and see how you would add it yourself

Comment: So all you need to know is the difference between two dates? If so, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript) has your answer

Comment: Problem is i will have to check for everymonth. and i only have installation date.

Comment: Given the nature of the question your name is ironic... :)

Comment: In which case you need to get the current date. If day > 8, add one to the month, then change the day to the 8th. Now you have the date to calculate the difference

Comment: @Liam should i take it as compliment or comment?

Comment: Definitely a comment o_O

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't need to get the current date. I want to show renew days for subscription. if someone installed on 4th Aug then it get renewed automatically on 4th Sep and next renew date will be 4th Oct. So, i want to show days remaining till 4th Oct.

Comment: What you exactly need is difference between current date & (installation date +30) . Am I correct ?

Comment: @Liam thanks thats what i understood.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine you do need the current date as both the starting date, and to figure out when the next 8th of the month is...

Comment: You'll have some edge cases, like if someone installed on 31 Jan, and renewed on 28 Feb, then the next renewal should be 28 or 31 Mar?

Comment: @Icycool every 30 days.

Comment: @Liam Name changed as suggested by you. :)

Comment: That conflicts with what you said, from 4th Aug to 4th Sep is 31 days

Comment: Every 30 days is easy, just find number of days between today and install date, then %30

Comment: @Icycool easy for you not for me. If it was easy for me then i would solved it by myself.

Comment: I mean it is easier than same day of every month. sorry if it sounds offending. So, the requirement is every 30 days or same day of every month?

Comment: @Icycool it wasn't offending. I am just saying that you guys have more experience than me. it is easy for you but not for me.

Comment: So... what is the requirement?

Comment: @Icycool i thought you are aware about it. and i think its good idea which you suggested above.

Comment: @Icycool i am talking about "Every 30 days is easy, just find number of days between today and install date, then %30"

Comment: Ah..ok. Just keep in mind that would mean only 360 days are covered in 12 renews =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the jsfiddle link

```
var last_renewed_date = moment([2017, 07, 29]);//aug 29

var next_renewal_date = last_renewed_date.add(1, 'month');//sep 29

today = moment(); //today is sep 9
var diff_in_days = next_renewal_date.diff(today, 'days');
console.clear();
console.log("last_renewed_date",last_renewed_date)
console.log("next_renewal_date",next_renewal_date)
console.log('diff_in_days', diff_in_days); //20 days left
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brfq9rea/1/

Comment: If you want it to be in period of 30 days, you need to put last_renewed_date.add(30, 'days') so it will add 30 days on every renewal date

Comment: The issue here will be time difference. For example a user in India will see 20 days but the user in US will see 21 days. It depends on your server time for which you need to adjust moment with the timezones

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try. Voted up.